# Is Differentiation Operator continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

$P$ is a vector space of all polynomial functions on $C[0,1]$
$p'$ is derivative of $p$.

Show that $T : P \to P \quad T(p)= p'$ is closed operator (the graph of T is closed) but not continuous.

Use $|| \; ||_{sup}$ (supremum norm) for polynomials.

On wikepedia it says that differentiation operator is not continuous how can I show it for this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any polynomial $x^{n}$. The sup norm of this is $1$. It's derivative is $nx^{n-1}$, the norm of which is $n$. Hence, the norm of the derivative can be made arbitrarily large. So the map is not bounded.

Comment: I know that it is not bounded. but this doesnt mean that it is not continuous as well

Comment: @Hitman The derivative is a linear operator, and for linear operators boundedness is equivalent to continuity.

Comment: Ok then what about the other part that how can we show that the operator is closed.

Comment: I think from Closed graph theorem we can say that it is not closed as well right ?

Comment: If yes, then I think there is a problem in the question as it clearly states that the operator is closed but not continuous

Comment: And can we use Closed graph theorem here as P is a vector space not Banach Space

Comment: P is not a Banach space as it is not closed in $C[0,1]$. Hence the closed graph theorem is not valid.

Comment: If your original question is answered, please mark it as such.